# Dotnet 5.0, error algunos servicios no se pueden construir

Tags: .net, razor, dotnetcore

Estoy iniciando en dotnet 5.0 y Razor, creando una webapp. Sin embargo en el momento me encuentro estancado por un error al intentar inyectar depencias, despues de mucho intentar no doy con la solución.

El error es el siguiente:
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: HospiEnCasaMascotas.App.Persistencia.iRepositorioMascota Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: HospiEnCasaMascotas.App.Persistencia.MascotaRepositorio': Unable to resolve service for type 'HospiEnCasaMascotas.App.Persistencia.AppContext' while attempting to activate 'HospiEnCasaMascotas.App.Persistencia.MascotaRepositorio'.)

Entiendo que el problema se encuentra en el repositorio indicado.

**MascotaRepositorio.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using HospiEnCasaMascotas.App.Dominio;
using System.Linq;

namespace HospiEnCasaMascotas.App.Persistencia{

    public class MascotaRepositorio : iRepositorioMascota
    {


        private readonly AppContext _appContext;

        public MascotaRepositorio(AppContext appContext){
            _appContext=appContext;
        }
        public Mascota AddMascota(Mascota mascota)
        {
            var MascotaAdicionada= _appContext.Mascotas.Add(mascota);
            _appContext.SaveChanges();
            return MascotaAdicionada.Entity;
               }

        public void DeleteMascota(int idMascota)
        {
            var MascotaEncontrada=_appContext.Mascotas.FirstOrDefault(m =>m.Id==idMascota);
            if(MascotaEncontrada==null)
            return;
            _appContext.Mascotas.Remove(MascotaEncontrada);
            _appContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Mascota> GetAllMascota()
        {
            return _appContext.Mascotas;
        }

        public Mascota GetMascota(int idMascota)
        {
            return _appContext.Mascotas.FirstOrDefault(m =>m.Id==idMascota);
        }

        public Mascota UpdateMascota(Mascota mascota)
        {
            var MascotaEncontrada=_appContext.Mascotas.FirstOrDefault(m =>m.Id==mascota.Id);

            if(MascotaEncontrada!=null)
            {
                MascotaEncontrada.NombreMascota=mascota.NombreMascota;
                MascotaEncontrada.Especie=mascota.Especie;
                MascotaEncontrada.Raza=mascota.Raza;
                MascotaEncontrada.generoMascota=mascota.generoMascota;
                MascotaEncontrada.Edad=mascota.Edad;

                _appContext.SaveChanges() ;
                

            }
            return MascotaEncontrada;
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
            services.AddSingleton<iRepositorioMascota, MascotaRepositorio>();
```

Agradezco la ayuda y pido excusas por la cantidad de código pegado.

Comment: Muestra el contenido de tu `AppContext`, por favor :D

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Logré resolver el problema :D

Answer (score 0):

El anterior error ha sido solucionado. Solamente debí cambiar un par de lineas.

```
// public MascotaRepositorio(AppContext appContext){
//     _appContext=appContext;
// }
```

Y agregar esta linea:
`private readonly AppContext _appContext = new AppContext();`

Estaré buscando más información para entender lo que sucedió.

Comment: Cuando utilizas DI (dependency injection/inyeccion de dependencia), todas las referencias que utilizas en las tipos (clases) inyectadas deben estar "disponibles" al momento de "utilizar" la clase objetivo. Es decir en tu caso **M ascotaRepositorio** lo estas inyectando, y los componentes que utiliza en su constructor (como AppContext) tambien deberia estar disponibles en tu localizador/proveedor de DI es decir debe tambien poder "inyectarse" o "resolverse". Hay que tener en cuenta que las referencias deben tener un scope y lifetime (ambito y tiempo de vida similar o mayor)